# mongoose race condition causes errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing favorite/unfavorite functionality in my client, and many fast requests causes wrong results, probably due race conditions.

What happens, that user sends a request to favorite post, then, fastly unfavorites, but unfavorite request resolves faster, and causes `Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): VersionError: No matching document found`. So my question would be how avoid this situation ? Is it possible to somehow to ensure that favorite resolves first ? Thanks!

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    favorites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
})

UserSchema.methods.favorite = function(id) {
  if (this.favorites.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    this.favorites.push(id);
  }

  return this.save();
};

UserSchema.methods.unfavorite = function(id) {
  if (this.favorites.indexOf(id) > -1) {
    this.favorites.remove(id);
  }
    return this.save();
};
```

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could you combine the functions and include an `else` so that it toggles, and you only ever have to call one function? E.g.:

```
UserSchema.methods.favorite = function(id) {
  if (this.favorites.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    this.favorites.push(id);
  } else {
    this.favorites.remove(id);
  }
  return this.save();
};
```